# SIGABRT playing movie

Tags: ios, button, ibaction, sigabrt, invalidargumentexception

The following code is taken from much larger code but I believe that this is the section that is giving me trouble. when I run it I get no errors but upon pressing the hardcoded button inside 'playMovie' that is suppose to execute, 'exit movie' I get the message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController exitMovie:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a4b350' I've done some research on this and found reasons why it does this but I can't seem to make sense of my case. I am a novice coder however so I am probably just missing something. Hope this is enough to solve the problem, if not I can send more code.

```
-(IBAction)playMovie{

UIButton *buttonPress = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[buttonPress addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(exitMovie:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
buttonPress.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1000.0, 1000.0);
 buttonPress.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:buttonPress];


NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"We_Cant_Elope" ofType:@"mov"]];

MPMoviePlayerController *playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
playerViewController.contentURL = url;
playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(120,300, 550, 400);


[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
[playerViewController play];


self.playerViewController = playerViewController;


}


-(IBAction)exitMovie{

[self.playerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.playerViewController stop];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to execute the wrong method; `exitMovie:` (note the colon) is **not** the same as `exitMovie`.  Perhaps the method should be defined as:

```
- (IBAction)exitMove:(id)sender
{
    ...
}
```

Which does match the `exitMovie:` selector.